# submit files failed when using perforce

Tags: submit, perforce

The story is like this:
1. I submit a group of files to the server with p4 gui, and some of the files are new (mark for add), e.g: a.cpp
2. But I need to back out the files down to some errors. So I back out and submit.
3. check out the files
3. Now, a.cpp become to a.cpp(0/2). when I submit the files, come out the following errors:
   Out of date ....
4. My question is , How can I submit the files again? Thanks. or Can I force to submit the files no matter what errors come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give very little information in your question, so this is just a guess: it seems that you are having trouble trying to add a.cpp because it has already been submitted by another changelist.

It looks like some other changelist has already submitted a.cpp, and has in fact submitted a second revision of it. So

```
a.cpp(0/2)
```

is trying to tell you that you have a.cpp open for add (you're at revision 0), while the repository records a.cpp at revision 2.

So you need to convert your add request to an edit request, as follows;

1. Make a copy of your a.cpp file somewhere safe
2. Revert a.cpp, so you no longer have it open
3. Sync a.cpp, to get revision #2 in your workspace
4. Open a.cpp for edit, so that you can change it
5. Copy your saved copy of a.cpp from step (1) into this workspace directory
6. Diff your copy to see what your changes are
7. If you're satisfied with the changes, submit them

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did as what you said. But, hmmm, there are more than 50 *.cpp.